# I cant get light to work with emission on render

Tags: rendering, emission

i created a plane and connected emission to materiel input and switched it to render to try and see my glass almost squid type thing but the light wasn't there and only the plane was lit up. The glass "squid" type thing has color and can bee seen but not as well as i have seen before in when put in render. Im sorry if i wasn't able to explain this very well it has only been a few days of using this and my first time trying to use emission. [image]

Comment: If you're using Eevee, Emission node doesn't emit light like a lamp would, and Glass needs some parameters to be tweaked, so maybe give more informations or share your file

Answer (score 3):

Unlike Cycles, which uses path traced light-bounces to calculate lighting for a scene, EEVEE uses fast approximations, which often need a bit of assistance to look close to their Cycles counterparts.

For emissions to work "properly" in EEVEE, at least 2 main things are necessary: Bloom, and baked lighting via an Irradiance Volume.

First, make sure Bloom is enabled:

[image: Bloom1]

Then, add an Irradiance Volume (under Light Probe in add menu). Scale it to the shape and size of where you think the "glow" should be cast. Don't make it too big, because if there are areas unaffected by the bloom, then you're just wasting performance unnecessarily. You can up the number of resolution subdivisions (default is 4) for the probe under the Object Data Properties tab if you want better quality.

After this, you will need to go to the Render Properties tab and select "Bake Indirect Lighting". Hit the bake button and allow it to calculate the indirect influence.

[image: Bloom2]

The final result looks something like this. If the look seems too low quality, you can adjust the bake settings and bake again as necessary. Just remember that this is a balance of quality and performance as is the case with many things.

[image: Bloom3]

Comment: I'd argue that "bloom" isn't a way to "make light work". Technically, it's more an esthetic choice and is a legacy from photography. Light alone doesn't bloom, volumes and irregular surfaces does.